# Using lottie-react-web, Im getting the following console error: <svg> attribute viewBox: Expected number, "0 0 undefined undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, svg, lottie

I've created a component from the [lottie-react-web](https://github.com/felippenardi/lottie-react-web) package.

```
import React from 'react';
import Lottie from 'lottie-react-web'
import animation from '../../src/animations/anim.json'

const LottieAnim = () => (
  <Lottie
    options = {{
      animationData: animation,
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
    }}
    width = "60px"
    height = "60px"
  />
)

export default LottieAnim
```

This works and builds successfully. When the DOM loads it is generating the wrapper div with the attributes defined. However, the svg in the div does not have defined viewbox parameters, as well as undefined width and height, along with the containing vectors inside the svg.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be `animationData: animationData.default`

See: https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for TypeScript it's better to do

```
import { default as animationData } from '../animation-with-blackjack-and-hooks.json'
```

and then

```
  const defaultOptions:Options = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true, 
    animationData: animationData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice'
    }
  };
```